# Term Paper Documents Disappeared

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery

I'm a college student working on my term paper, and I've encountered a perplexing issue that's sent my stress levels through the roof.

I was diligently working on my paper, making progress, and feeling good about it when, all of a sudden, disaster struck – my documents had mysteriously disappeared from my computer. Now, I've been racking my brain to figure out if I might have inadvertently done something to cause this.

Thinking back, I recall a few actions that could be potential culprits. I was trying to organize my files and clean up my desktop clutter. In the process, I moved a few folders around, thinking it would help me stay more organized. Little did I know that these innocent attempts at decluttering would lead to such a nightmare.

I've checked my recent documents, and the trash bin, and even ran a search on my computer, but the files seem to have vanished into thin air. I didn't delete them intentionally, and I'm absolutely clueless about why this happened.

I've got backups, but unfortunately, they're not the most recent ones, and I've put so much effort into the version I was working on. I'm feeling the pressure, as the deadline for my term paper is looming, and I really can't afford to start from scratch.

If anyone has any tech-savvy advice, tips, or tricks to recover lost documents or understand why this might have happened due to the actions I mentioned, I would be forever grateful. I am using a Toshiba Portege R30-A laptop with a Windows 10 system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try searching for the files using a third-party tool, such as Agent Ransack, https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/. Also, do you use a cloud-based version of Word? If so, the files might be out there.

Comment: For future reference, treat this as a learning experience and make regular backups of your important work.

Comment: No backup? No pity.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you can't even locate the file, I can really only think of 2 things.

1. Go to "File" > "Open" > "Recover Unsaved Documents" and check if the latest version of your file is there. (see [video instructions here](https://youtu.be/17Mn1FyOi_g?si=TGkp8gN-TwqculID&t=23))
2. Use a recovery tool as suggested by Rohit. Note, that even using the browser will overwrite data on your system, so you might want to stop all actions on your computer and try the recovery first.

In case you can find the document and you have the file version history activated on your Windows PC, then you will also find older versions of your document when you right-click on it and select "Restore previous versions".

And just for future documents that are important to you, use at least 1 of the following 3 backup options:

1. If you have Office 365 store your document in your free One-Drive cloud space that comes with it. You can also activate Auto-Save which will save the document every few seconds and you will have a detailed version history.
2. Use a cloud service of your choice (e.g. Google Drive) and create at least one folder on your computer that automatically syncs to that cloud service. Then you can put all your important documents into that folder.
3. And in case you don't like cloud services for some reason > regular USB flash drive backups (or other external hard drive backups)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) for the odd time I have deleted something.  There is a free version.  It should succeed as long as you haven't written to your disk since then.  If you have written to your disk, it may fail or only recover part of the file.

Blurb from their site

> **Superior file recovery**
> Recuva can recover pictures, music, documents, videos, emails or any other file type you’ve lost. And it can recover from any rewriteable media you have: memory cards, external hard drives, USB sticks and more!
>
> **Recovery from damaged disks**
> Unlike most file recovery tools, Recuva can recover files from damaged or newly formatted drives. Greater flexibility means greater chance of recovery.
>
> **Deep scan for buried files**
> For those hard to find files, Recuva has an advanced deep scan mode that scours your drives to find any traces of files you have deleted.
>
> **Securely delete files**
> Sometimes you want a file gone for good. Recuva’s secure overwrite feature uses industry- and military-standard deletion techniques to make sure your files stay erased.

Note, I am not associated with them in any way.